# How to cite Stack Overflow surveys?

Tags: support, citation

I'd like to cite this survey: https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018/

Should I cite this as a report or a regular Web page? Also, who should I put down as the author of the page/report?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about the annual Stack Overflow Developer Survey should be asked on Meta Stack Overflow, not here. See the [survey tag description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/survey)

Comment: I asked on Meta Stack Overflow https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407220/how-to-cite-stack-overflow-surveys

Answer (score -1):

> Should I cite this as a report or a regular Web page? Also, who should I put down as the author of the page/report?

Clicking on the 'share to Google' link at the bottom gives this text: "[Stack Overflow Developer Survey 2018](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018/)", and a ***suggested*** post. It is a report on the results of the developer survey of 2018 presented on a webpage.

You can access the raw data and create your own report, the database is covered by the "[Open Database License (ODbL) v1.0](https://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/1.0/)". Moderator animuson informs me that the data in the database is not covered by the [cc by-sa 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), only the ODbL.

Comment: Creative Commons doesn't apply to the developer survey results in any way. Only the ODbL.

Comment: @animuson - Thank you. I'll update the answer. I thought all information collected from users was covered by CC, and thus the survey is also bound by it.

Comment: @Rob Everything posted by users to parts of the network falls under CC, the survey isn't considered part of the network. That's why.